# Variable that refers to many uiimageviews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, iboutlet

Okay so what I want to do is I have an app with many uiimageviews that you can move and do actions with them. Instead of creating many outlets for each, how can i create one variable that refers to all these outlets (**not IBOutletCollection** because i would have to use array and arrays dont have properties that uiimageviews do. Ive tried that if youre positive it works please show me the code). For example I have many uiimageviews, variable = all my uiimageviews

So then [variable move]; it moves all the uiimageviews. (NOT BITWISE & or && OPERATOR)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating all of the `UIImageView` instances and wrapping them in a single transparent `UIView`. Then when you want to move all the UIImageViews you'd just need to move their wrapper (said UIView).

**update**

```
UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bigFrame];

for (size_t i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:someUIImage];
    [wrapper addSubview:iv];
    [iv release];
}
[self.view addSubview:wrapper];
[wrapper release];
```

This code creates an uiview that has 10 uiimageviews inside it. When you move that view (wrapper view) the child image views will move with it.

Comment: which part don't you understand?

Comment: the actual code and the xib.... so do i just put a view over it and mve the view and then will it move the particles. how would i wrap them?